# Telerik rad combobox multiple column databinding

Tags: javascript, jquery, telerik, radcombobox

**Iam new to telerik controls.I have anchor tag of "Show all Account.. " in footer template of radcombobox**

```
<telerik:RadComboBox runat="server" ID="rcmdExpAc" TabIndex="22" EmptyMessage="" HighlightTemplatedItems="true"
    AllowCustomText="true" Width="235" OnClientDropDownOpening="OnClientDropDownOpeningExpAc" OnClientDropDownClosing="OnClientDropDownClosingExpAc">
    <ItemTemplate>
      <div class="combo-item-template">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td style="width: 40px;">
              <span> <%# Eval("colAccCode")%> </span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 400px;">
              <span> <%# Eval("colAccName")%> </span>
            </td>
            <td style="width: 110px;">
              <span> <%# Eval("colAcTypeName")%></span>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </ItemTemplate>
 <FooterTemplate>
   <a id="ExpenseAccount" class="blue" style="text-decoration: underline;" href="#signup" name="signup" rel="leanModal">New Account...</a>
   <a id="ElnkShowIncomeAccount" class="blue" style="text-decoration: underline; cursor: pointer;" onclick="EShowAllOrPaymentAccount(this);" >Show All Accounts...</a>
 </FooterTemplate>
</telerik:RadComboBox>`
```

On show all accounts  click the ajax call is called and it is rebind with combobox but the combo box only bind one column from database ...here is the code for ajax call.....

```
function EShowAllOrPaymentAccount(event) {
        var dropDown = $find("rcmdExpAc");
        if (event.innerHTML == "Show All Accounts...") {

            $.ajax({
                url: "../Handlers/Expense.ashx",
                type: 'GET',
                data: {
                    rType: "GetAllPaymentAccRecord",
                    CompanyID: $('#compid').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                    dropDown.clearItems();
                    $.each(data, function (indx, itm) {
                        var comboItem = new Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItem();

                        comboItem.set_value(itm.colAccId);
                        comboItem.set_text(itm.colAccCode);

                        dropDown.trackChanges();
                        dropDown.get_items().add(comboItem);
                        dropDown.commitChanges();

                    });

                },
                error: function (a, b, c) {
                    alert(a + " " + b + " " + c);
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

I want to bind `Eval("colAccName")%>,Eval("colAccCode")%>,Eval("colAcTypeName")%>` are earlier defined in radcombo . but i only find a way of binding one column against colAccID... Please guide me how to bind 3 column from database which are defined in template in this javascript code.

Answer (score 0):

You should define a **ClientItemTemplate** as shown in this [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/clienttemplates/defaultcs.aspx). 
It is used when you create your combo items client-side.

You can also use **Attributes** to store additional info about the item (text, value + AccountType, AccountCode, etc.). The syntax can be also seen in the [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/combobox-client-templates-overview.html).